# weird @^ in log files

Tags: hardware, cpu

i recently checked my log files and found lines just consisting of "@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^"
like specific lines have been removed from my log files, during the system bootup. here are 4 images.
https://ibb.co/x13Wq0f
https://ibb.co/N9srm9w
https://ibb.co/SQzDWnn
https://ibb.co/s6DbMVm

i have seen and been prey to CPU microcode exploits in the past, that can output the same symbols "@^" due to the system not recognising the exploited code and cant interoperate it.
so is their anyway to know if my CPU has been exploited or is this just a glitch.

Answer (score 1):

^@ is the ASCII NULL character in caret notation. Generally means a bit of garbage in the log file. Nothing I would be worried about

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caret_notation

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply,
by Garbage i assume you could mean, pulling the power without performing a shutdown so on the next boot it will try write the Garbage from the power disconnect?